# A Question on Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have a general question about the dominated convergence theorem. The theorem states that if I have a sequence of measurable functions that are bounded by an integrable function and converge pointwise almost everywhere to some function f, then f is integrable. My question is concerning showing that the sequence of functions is bounded.

Aside from looking to find an integrable majorant directly (the function bounding my sequence) are there other options? Namely, are there special functions or instances where a function will always have an integrable majorant without requiring one to actually find the bounding function?

Comment: This is sort of a backwards way of looking at it. You apply LDCT when you have a dominating function. In many real problems, identifying the dominating function is quite trivial. But the generalization is not to identify circumstances when a dominating function exists without constructing it. Instead the generalization is the Vitali Convergence Theorem, which furnishes a necessary and sufficient condition. This essentially says that if $|f_n|$ have uniformly small integrals over small sets, and if their supports are uniformly "almost finite", then a.e. convergence implies $L^1$ convergence.

Comment: (Cont.) These two conditions are called uniform integrability and tightness respectively. It is easy to show that the hypotheses of LDCT imply the hypotheses of VCT. I am not sure whether there actually are any simple examples where the hypotheses of VCT are satisfied and the hypotheses of LDCT are not.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes finding the dominating function is difficult and a lot of times it can be tedious. Are there special cases where I can show that a function with certain properties is dominated by an integrable function without having to always find it?

Comment: Not really. As I said, this sort of question boils down to "what is a necessary and sufficient condition for a.e. convergence to imply $L^1$ convergence"? The necessary and sufficient conditions are the VCT hypotheses. Consequently anything you use to prove that a.e. convergence implies $L^1$ convergence will straightforwardly imply the VCT hypotheses. If explicitly finding a dominating function is hard, directly proving the VCT hypotheses is probably the only easier approach.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. Having the VCT definitely makes this a less interesting question.